# PCB Mount DC Connector /Jack

Tags: dc, connector

Why does this DC connector have holes at the ends of the  pins?

[image: DC Jack am referring to]

Answer (score 5):

The holes are their to provide more reinforcement to the wires directly attached to the DC jack if it is not mounted on a PCB and is attached to a external panel or is left hanging.

One can thread the wire through the DC jack and then twist it and solder it for a robust connection.